# Images not showing in react project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, return

I'm currently working on a project, a social media type website where people can create posts and add an image to it. So far this is working, the post is created and the image is being saved locally to a folder. The issue I'm having in the home.js file is that the image is not showing on page render, instead it is showing an image icon with the alt text and telling me in the console:

GET http://localhost:3001/images/1664455878582selfie.png 404 (Not Found)
I am not yet getting the link from the SQL database but adding it manually to the code to first check that it will show.
This is the code on the home.js file:

```
const image = 'http://localhost:3001/images/1664455878582selfie.png';
```

And the return function:

```
    return (
<div className='home'>

<div className='post'>
  <img src={image} alt="postphoto"/>
</div>

</div>
)
```

The images are stored in project/server/images and the server is hosted on port 3001.
The code is available on https://github.com/ohsand/groupomania2 if this helps!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The direct variable image link doesn't work in React. You should ***import*** the image first and then use it. Given below the `demo code`, you need to modify based on your project.

```
import image from './images/1664455878582selfie.png';

<div className='post'>
  <img src={image} alt="postphoto"/>
</div>
```

`'./images/1664455878582selfie.png'` section will be according to your ***File-Structure***.

Comment: Thanks for the help, It seems that it doesn't find it with http://localhost:3001/images/1664455878582selfie.png as the import for some reason...
How will I be able to create a loop which adds the correct image for the posts with my SQL database? Because even if this did work I can't import every image name automatically, I'd like to just replace {image} with the path stored in the sql database for each post.